# While loops in JES?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, jes

I am a beginner so be nice

Trying to change this code to include a while loop or modify it use all while loops

Can any one help

```
def shrink():
 picture = makePicture(pickAFile())
 newPicture = makeEmptyPicture(getWidth(picture) /2, getHeight(picture) /2)
#time for our shrinking ray gun to work
 while x in range(getWidth(picture)):
  while y in range(getHeight(picture)):
   originalPixel = getPixel(picture, x, y)
   color = getColor(originalPixel)
   newPixel = getPixel(newPicture, x / 2, y / 2)
   setColor(newPixel, color)
 show(picture)
#Show and tell 
 show(newPicture)
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to swap this for `while` loops? Using `for` loops is more idiomatic anyway. However, what have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Well it is for university. They wanted us to change it to teach us how to use while loops. Unfortunately we have to try and work out the answer and then we are taught how to do it after the fact.I guess i am more looking for a good explanation on while loops .

Comment: Then it's a point for you to research it. That's why you get given the answer afterwards; SO isn't for doing your homework for you and you haven't shown any indication of research on the matter. [While loop Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm)

Comment: this what i have which just keeps looping

Comment: sorry not sure how to use this forum effectively

Comment: You can't just substitute `for` with `while`. Please take time to read the tutorial I have linked for you.

Comment: The loops loop forever because they are doing the exact same thing on each iteration. There is no `while/in` loop. You have a while loop whose condition check is using `in`. The for loop is the correct loop here as you know how many iteration you will do before the loop starts. To make it while you'll need a variable external to the loop that is incremented on each iteration and the while will simply check that the max value has not yet been reached.